# How to fix apt-get install / update not working on my Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux but the `apt-get install` command is not working to install any application on my system.
Mustafa1112221
I think it's got something to do with my Kali Linux repository `sources.list` file. The file may be empty or the current repo address is wrong or experiencing a problem.

Please, could someone provide me a link to the Kali official `sources.list` file?

Comment: Is it a freshly installed Kali Linux?

Comment: Hi, The last edit make your question unclear. please keep it as it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open a terminal and follow these instructions:

1. Type `sudo -i`
2. Type in your password.
3. Type `touch /etc/apt/sources.list`
4. Type `chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list`
5. Type `echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list`
6. Type `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6`
7. Type `apt update`
8. Now install whatever it is that you want to install.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because Google led me to it when I searched for why 'apt-get update' didn't do anything.  It was the 2nd answer from the google-gods and quickly fixed the problem.

Comment: What i get on step `6 ` is `gpg:keyserver failed: Network is unreachable`. How should I solve that .. installed Kali and all I see is the bash shell mode.

Comment: @TomaTomov : Are you able to access the internet? Are you working behind a proxy?

Comment: I think I am not able to access it. No. I am not behind proxy. How to check if i am connected to internet through the command line? What I found is that I need `wpa_supplicant` but I can't install it without the net connection I guess because when I try I get `Network connection failed`. I am really sorry for my confusing answers but I am total newbie. For now :)

Comment: @TomaTomov : `apt-get update` does require an internet connection because it downloads information regarding the latest packages and their versions from the repository. You won't be able to take update unless you have an internet connection. To check if you are connected try pinging a website. for example, `ping duckduckgo.com` and see if it replies. This is a simple but not a sure shot to check your internet connectivity. Depending upon your environment and firewall configurations, you may or may not get a reply.

Comment: I am at work now but will try it as soon as I get home and will give a feedback. Thank you very much !

Comment: got error gnupgX not installed error at step 6 but I moved on and it worked anyway,